# Подтвердить или опровергнуть факт взлома

Tags: google-chrome, безопасность, https, csp

Доброго времени суток.

Вчера утром, при авторизации на [Яндекс.Почте](https://mail.yandex.ru), Google Chrome    (57.0.2987.133, win7 home basic) выдал ошибку NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.
До этого все было нормально, ничего необычного не делал.

На страницах сервисов Яндекс.Радио, Яндекс.Музыка, Яндекс.Диск(остальные не пробовал), после нажатия "вход" ничего не происходит, а через секунд десять, появляется окошечко, сообщающее о неполадках. Если при этом посмотреть вкладку, инструментов разработчика, Network - то появляется несколько красных строк, с типом csp(Content Security Policy).

Поисковые запросы по поводу ошибки, выдают кучу однообразных страниц, где предлагается решить данную проблему способами от "принудительного отключения проверок сертификатов" до "удаления старых и скачивания новых сертификатов в хранилище windows".

После проделывания некоторых вещей:

- Убедиться в правильной настройке времени
- Очистить историю, кэш, куки
- Переустановить хром
- Отключить расширения
- Приостановить работу антивируса

, которые не помогли, углубился немного в тему и появился вопрос:

**Как убедиться, что НЕКТО|НЕЧТО сидит(или отсутствует) на канале связи и пытается втюхать левый сертификат?** Или другими словами как стать уверенным, что это программная ошибка у меня, а не взлом?

> а в настройках интернет эксплорера ничего не меняли? – pavel

В настройках IE ничего не меняли, он также ругается на Яндекс.Почту.

> касперский любит сертификаты подменять – tCode

Касперский не установлен. Установлены avast и total security 360.

Comment: а в настройках интернет эксплорера ничего не меняли?

Comment: касперский любит сертификаты подменять

Comment: @pavel В настройках IE ничего не меняли, он также ругается на Яндекс.Почту. IE точно также ругается как и хром.

Comment: @tCode Касперский не установлен. Установлены avast и total security 360.

Comment: А вы посмотрите на сам сертификат и то, чем он заверен. Возможно, уже оттуда будет очевидно, где подвох.

Comment: Посмотрите, какой сертификат пытается загрузится. У яндекса он yandex.com.tr/Выдан: Yandex CA/Истекает: четверг, 20 декабря 2018 г. Yandex CA в свою очередь выдан Certum Trusted Network CA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как убедиться, что НЕКТО|НЕЧТО сидит(или отсутствует) на канале связи и пытается втюхать левый сертификат? Или другими словами как стать уверенным, что это программная ошибка у меня, а не взлом?

Легко: открыть с другого устройства. Например, с телефона через вайфай.

Если там будет та же ошибка, то где-то по пути подменяется сертификат.

Если ошибки не будет, то что-то идёт не так непосредственно на самом компе. Однако, это не означает, что никто не пытается подсунуть левый сертификат - так вполне может поступать троян на самом компе (хотя странно, что он в таком случае сертификат не установил в систему).